# Moves scroll position on hover of absolute element in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

So I am having an issue which I have simplified and can be played around with here: http://www.cssdesk.com/XL5Ve.

If I have say three elements floated left, 33.33% which contain an absolutely positioned div element that grows on hover, it causes the scroll position of the page to change when hovering on the first one IF the top of that container is slightly cut off the top of the screen (can be seen in that attached GIF).

[image]

If all the elements are in full view, nothing moves, but scroll down so the top of the box is slightly cut off and hovering in it moves the whole screen.

This only happens in Chrome, has anyone has experience with this? Can anyone suggest a workaround? Tried doing the animation in jQuery instead of CCS but it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Checked in Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit). No errors found!

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat - My Chrome is Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) as are other machines I have tested this on, you only have to slightly cut the top off is this possibly why?

Comment: I could reproduce it by zooming out (4-5x ctrl Minus), making the window less high and then scrolling down. But I wouldn't know what causes it or how to fix it.

Comment: @PeterB it really is an odd one, tearing my hair out trying to figure out why!

Comment: what is `padding:600px 0 ` on body ? and `margin:1000px 0` on the box row ?

Comment: @MihaiT This was just to make the page large enough to be able to scroll down far enough to reproduce the issue.